# Remove parent but keep children using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove the parent and keep the children in my HTML using jQuery. This works:

```
$('#my_span').children().insertBefore('#my_span').end().end().remove();
```

However, it removes the text and comment node types - how can I amend this so that I keep the text?

Happy to do this with pure Javascript too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Cᴏʀʏ says, `unwrap()` should help you acheive this.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
$('#my_span').parent().html($('#my_span').html());
```

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using the [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method in the jQuery library? If it leaves text and comments in place, you could reduce your code to:

```
$('#my_span').unwrap();
```

If you don't want all of the children removed, you could extend jQuery with the following modified unwrap method ([found it here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-unwrap-plugin/)), which will replace an element with its children:

```
$.fn.myUnwrap = function() {
    this.parent(':not(body)').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith( this.childNodes );
    });
    return this;
};
```

And then using it would be easy:

```
$('#my_span').myUnwrap();
```

Comment: I switched away from unwrap because for different elements like `ul` which has children `li` - I don't want to remove them but unwrap will. To overcome this I have to use a condition to check what sort of element it is and then work out depth of unwrapping and this won't work for me.

Comment: Could you show us the actual HTML you're working with? Also, `<li>` elements can't exist outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` -- unwrapping them *should* remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$($("#my_span")[0].inntHTML).insertBefore("#my_span");
$("#my_span").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="my_span">
  <h2>headline</h2>
  <p>Hallo Du!</p>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery

```
var my_span_Content = $("#my_span").contents();
$("#my_span").replaceWith(my_span_Content);
```

HTML Result

```
<h2>headline</h2>
<p>Hallo Du!</p>
```

1. You with jQuery ***.contents*** just take the content from the
   container (*#my_span*) and keep it as *my_span_Content*.
2. Then just replace the container with its content via ***.replaceWith***