# jQuery move element up to parent level

Tags: jquery

I have this DOM structure:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input />
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to move the input up one level and the label removed, so that I have:

```
<div>
  <input />
</div>
```

I have a reference to the div but there are no id's or classes on the label or input (its generated by a plugin widget). I tried to remove the label but that of course also removes the input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove parent but keep children using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756930/remove-parent-but-keep-children-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) on the input element to achieve this

```
$('div > label > input').unwrap()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pLrEc/)