# How can I remove an element but keep its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML like this:

```
<a href="#">
    <span>children</span>
</a>
<button>click</button>
```

I want to remove that `<a>` but keep that `<span>`. How can I do that?

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   /* to remove the link, but not the span */
});
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756930/remove-parent-but-keep-children-using-jquery

Comment: And if those dupes don't do it, you can use `$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('span').unwrap();
});`

Comment: @j08691 Well played .. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
$a = $("a")
$a.replaceWith($a.children());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
   /* to remove the link, but not the span */
   
  var inner_html = $("#my_anchor").html();
  $("#parent").html(inner_html)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  
<a href="#" id="my_anchor">
    <span>children</span>
</a>
  
</div>

<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote .. But that's odd .. Your answer is given after my question being marked as duplicate ..!